# How to pass props on React-Navigation so the navigated component can re-render when those props are changed

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-props

im trying to navigate from component A to B  passing props this way (as options):

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("B",{
            retrievePlayingNow:this.props.retrievePlayingNow, // props come from component C
            skipSong: this.skipsong, // this is a function

          });
    }
```

so when i call a function 'skipSong' it changes the props on component C (which is a father component of A)props on A changes but on component B props remain the same and it doesn't re-render to show the new info. Is there any other way i can do this using React-Navigation?

Answer (score 0):

This is where a `state management libraries` comes into action.

Well, I use [redux](https://redux.js.org/). Here you can store the data in the global store which can be accessible by any of the components.

So put the variable `retrievePlayingNow` into the redux store from `C` component, and access it by `B` component. So when `C` (or anyone) changes the value of that variable, all those components using accessing that variable (including `B`) will re-render.

Another advantage of using any `state management library` is that you don't need to make a hierarchy of components to pass props as you have done `C -> A -> B`. All you can do is dispatch the variable into the store from `C` and directly access it by `B`

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, unfortunately I didn't implement redux on time and now in the current state of my app is not an option. Next time i think i will. I'll keep looking, thanks!!

Comment: Well, you can anytime add the redux in your application. Just don't modify your application, just let only future components use the redux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DeviceEventEmitter to add listener events to re-render without using redux.